# Error: Method 'toDouble' cannot be called on 'int?' while creating an app on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi I am having an error while creating an app on Flutter

```
Error: Method 'toDouble' cannot be called on 'int?' because it is potentially null.
Try calling using ?. instead.
                          value: SliderValue.toDouble(),

                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

Anyone can help me

Error Screenshots

1. [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1lhr.png)
2. [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqRet.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SliderValue can be `null`. you probably have it defined somewhere as

```
int? SliderValue;
```

You could change it to

```
int SliderValue = 0;
```

to fix it, or alternatively use

```
value: SliderValue?.toDouble() ?? 0,
```

to handle the case of when it's `null`

Answer (score 0):

Add '?' to the SliderValue:

SliderValue?.toDouble()